# Classname in static methods of abstract classes

Tags: matlab

I would like to access the class name of the concrete class that's invoking a static method implemented in an abstract superclass.

This is the code (part of) of the abstract superclasss:

```
classdef (Abstract) AbstractJobProcessor < handle

    properties (Abstract, Constant)
        VERSION_MAJOR;
        VERSION_MINOR;
        LAST_MODIFIED;
    end 

    ...


methods (Static)
    function res = getVersionMajor;
        res = AbstractJobProcessor.VERSION_MAJOR;
    end 

    function res = getVersionMinor
        res = AbstractJobProcessor.VERSION_MINOR;
    end

    function res = getVersionInfo
        res = sprintf('**CLASSNAME**: v%d.%02d (last modified: %s)',... 
            AbstractJobProcessor.VERSION_MAJOR,...
            AbstractJobProcessor.VERSION_MINOR,...
            AbstractJobProcessor.LAST_MODIFIED);
    end

end
...
```

Basically, I would like to access the classname of the concrete subclass and use it in the method `getVersionInfo` in place of the string `**CLASSNAME**`.

All the methods returning meta information about a class (that I have found in the documentation) require a reference to an instance of the class (like, for example, `mc = metaclass(object)`).

Comment: Can you show what one of your subclasses looks like? I'm unable to create a subclass that works with your superclass the way that you've set it up.

Comment: You may be able to get it by inspecting stack. But I think it is better to pass the instance or class name to this method.

Comment: No late static bindings in MATLAB. dbstack is probably your best option.

Comment: I may have made some mistake but currently `VERSION_MAJOR`, `VERSION_MINOR` and `LAST_MODIFIED` are returning `[]` when calling `getVersionInfo` (even if they are defined to something else in derived class).

Comment: May be there is another question: Does matlab support (Constant, abstract) properties? I cannot find any explicity sentence in the doc.

Comment: @AntonioSesto They are supported (i.e. it foces the subclass to implement the properties); however, when you're accessing them from within your static methods you're using the superclass name to refer to them so they are accessing the superclass values ([]) rather than the subclass values.

Comment: @Suever not saying you are wrong, but that renders the whole point of static abstract properties useless

Answer (score 1):

The below function will give you what you want - subclass name, that was used when invoking an (inherited) static superclass method. Just call it inside your superclass method like you would any normal function:

```
className = getStaticCallingClassName();
```

What it *does* handle:

- Both the case when method was invoked programmatically (i.e. by a running script / function), as well as when it was invoked from the command window.
- Arbitrarily nested package names (i.e. classes located inside directories prefixed with `+`).

What it *does not* handle:

- Does not work if the static method is called in a non-static context, i.e. on an object instance. But you should not be using such syntax anyway. This would've been possible if we were able to use `evalin` with `'caller'` workspace recursively, but it does not work this way.

A brief explanation behind the idea: second entry in the stack trace, produced by `dbstack`, would correspond to the superclass, which we can use to extract the static method name. The next steps depend on:

1. If the method is invoked programmatically, third stack entry would point us to a line in the the parent script/function which we need to read, e.g. using `dbtype`. All that's left to do is extract the subclass name using `regexp` based on the method name.
2. If the method is invoked from command window, we query the last command and use that as the input for our regular expression.

Note that even if stack has 3 entries or more, it doesn't mean that the method was invoked programmatically. For example, if we've stopped on a breakpoint somewhere and invoke the method from command window, stack trace would be long, but `regexp` based on the line from the third stack trace entry will not give us the answer. In this case we fall back to the command window approach.

**Warning**: it heavily relies on undocumented features and may break in any feature release. Tested on Matlab 2015b, but should work on most previous releases as well. Some may say it is quite dirty, but it works very well, and it's the only method that I'm aware of to achieve such a behavior.

```
function [className, fullPath] = getStaticCallingClassName()
    ST = dbstack('-completenames');
    % First one is getStaticCallingClassName, second one is the superclass
    methodName = char(regexp(ST(2).name, '[^\.]([^.]*)$', 'match'));
    % matches string (combination of alphanumeric/underscore/dot characters) preceeding the given method call.
    pattern = sprintf('[\\w.-]*(?=.%s)', methodName);

    % If the parent called static method programmatically, we should be able to find it via the next (third) stack trace
    if length(ST) > 2
        command = evalc('dbtype(ST(3).file, num2str(ST(3).line))');
        className = char(regexp(command, pattern, 'match'));
    else % was likely called from command window. Long stack trace means that we're simply waiting in a breakpoint somewhere
        className = []; % go straight to command window approach
    end

    if isempty(className) % means that static method was called directly from command window
        javaHistory = com.mathworks.mlservices.MLCommandHistoryServices.getSessionHistory();
        command = char(javaHistory(end));
        className = char(regexp(command, pattern, 'match'));
    end

    fullPath = which(className);
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a *workaround*. According to the MATLAB documentation:

- '*Ordinary* methods define functions that operate on objects of the class',
- '*Static* methods are (1) associated with a class, but (2) not with specific instances of that class'.

You can have both aspects of static methods if you call an ordinary method with an empty object array.

For example, suppose we have a base class:

```
classdef base
    methods 
        function obj = base()
            disp('constructor called')
        end
        function dispClassName(obj)
            disp(['class name = ', class(obj)]);
        end
    end
end
```

and a subclass

```
classdef sub < base
end
```

Now call the methods as follows (this will not invoke any constructor):

```
>> base.empty.dispClassName
class name = base
>> sub.empty.dispClassName
class name = sub
```

A real solution (for which I did an enhancement request 03315500 to MathWorks) would be to extend the MATLAB language with a method attribute 'Class' to define methods that are associated with the invoking class (similar to the Python @classmethod decorator). Methods of this class would automatically receive the metaclass of the invoking function as a first argument. With such an extension we could define a base class:

```
% Future MATLAB syntax extension
classdef base
    methods(Class) % New method attribute ‘Class’
        function dispClassName(cls) % implicit argument (meta.class)
            disp(['class name = ' cls.Name ]);
        end
    end
end
```

and a subclass

```
classdef sub < base
end
```

and call

```
>> base.dispClassName
class name = base
>> sub.dispClassName
class name = sub
```

Comment: See [link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/empty.html) The `empty()` method creates an empty object array. It does not call the class constructor. Example `double.empty()` returns `[]`

Comment: Thanks! I've learned something new today. I was wrong: it did work, but calling my overloaded `display` on the result triggered the error.